# Adobe Premiere - Using crop effect - exported video still has black bars

Tags: adobe-premiere, crop

Trying to remove tiny black bars from left and right using crop effect
As you can see - crop rectangle is adjusted properly
But exported video still have that black bars
What is wrong, pls ?

[image]

Comment: Did you resize it after crop to fill the frame?

Comment: @RomeoNinov - no, I suppose crop - is crop - and that's enough. Tell me pls, what should I do, how to resize ?

Comment: When you crop you have check box - **Zoom**, select it.

Comment: @RomeoNinov - but I don't want to zoom my video. I just want to crop it, i.e. change video dimensions, i.e. width - in this case, i.e. to cut black areas

Comment: Presumably you'll have to change your entire project dimensions.

Comment: Also have you try to render cropped clip to see if the borders exist in the end material?

Comment: @RomeoNinov - yes the black bars are there. Once again - let's say starting dimensions are 640 x 352px, and black bars are 10px each. I simpy want to cut that black bars and get the video as 620 x 352. I hope that's clear now

Comment: @Tetsujin - yes but the new dimensions should be original dimensions - minus - cutted black bars. Let's say starting dimensions are 640 x 352px, and black bars are 10px each. I simpy want to cut that black bars and get the video as 620 x 352.

Comment: Is it the output file of rendering with dimensions 620 x 352?

Comment: @RomeoNinov - No, I'm always getting 640 x 352 and with black bars

Comment: I am not familiar with Premiere, but have you try to create custom output dimensions? If it's not possible you should use Zoom (to fill the frame).

Comment: @RomeoNinov - once again - I don't want to `ZOOM` - I want to `CROP`. If you're not familiar whit premiere pls stop losing your and my time.

Comment: Hhave you set your sequence to the correct frame size? Presumably no, or the bars would already be gone

Comment: @Tetsujin - I cannot set the sequence frame size because I dont' know in advance what is the width of black bars. 10px is just an example. And I'm expecting to get such an info for example by dragging handles on crop rectangle, but there is now such an info.

Comment: You are going to have to use trial & error then, I'm afraid. In future, shoot looser so you don't have this kind of difficulty re-aligning your frame afterwards, especially for something as simple as a talking heads shot. Even with the shot as you have it, it really wouldn't hurt to lose some of the neckline if you have to keep the top of the frame. Also note that 620x352 isn't going to fit anyone's screen, anywhere, so unless it's free-floating in a web page etc it's going to pillar-box..

Comment: @Tetsujin - So I have to use trial and error method using the "most powerful"  and so expensive software. At the same time - there are so many online services and totally free desktop applications to remove black bars - just by dragging crop handles.

Comment: Basically, you're trying to do something a regular video suite was never designed to do. It's designed to make TV & movies, which have pre-determined frame sizes. It's not really set up to make randomly-cropped internet videos. You're trying to bend it to your will because your shot was too tight to fit a regular frame.

Comment: @Tetsujin - you say -  "It's not really set up to make randomly-cropped internet videos". Try to say this to Adobe

Comment: You're just trying to do this all backwards, then wondering why you're having so much trouble. Usually the very first decision made on a production is what aspect ratio it's going to be shot in. No-one's going to shoot 2.39:1 for a month before thinking "Oh… what about the IMAX?"

Comment: @Tetsujin - Once again - there are so many free apps where you can have any dimensions of clip and any dimensions of black bars - the black bars will be removed just by a pair of clicks. That logic - about standard dimensions - is for cave age.

Comment: There's nothing else I can add. You want something not planned for in program-making & you want it just because you didn't plan ahead. Finish your project in its current aspect ratio then find one of these freebie online services to crop it. Done.

Comment: @Tetsujin - it's done for you. For me - it is so far from 'done' because I paid that software, expecting to work with any video dimensions. Anyway, thanks for your efforts, you helped me to understand that I'm deceived

Comment: It does work with any dimensions. You just have to decide them first. You worked your project backwards. You weren't deceived, you just didn't think it through properly before you started. Remember the adage 'A bad workman always blames his tools.' Of course, if you didn't want to pay all that money for Premier, you could have just used DaVinci Resolve for free. It's at least as good, if not better. Same as with your aspect ratio, do your research before you commit.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I'm not author of that clip. WIll you say me - that I need to run around the world and cry - PLEASE, MAKE VIDEOS WITH ONLY CERTAIN DIMENSIONS ?

Comment: I've posted an answer to the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

If your clip is not the same aspect ratio as your output [project/sequence] then the editor will have to pad to fit; either by letter-boxing, or in your case pillar-boxing.

There is no way around this except to match your project to your clip, or zoom your clip to hit or overshoot your frame edges.

Comment: Seems you didn't understand me at all. I `don't want to zoom` my video and I `don't want the black bars`. I just want to `cut` black bars `and get smaller with of video`. But to do this I need to know the black bars size. Or define the crop area by crop rectangle. And that seems impossible. Once again - I want to cut black bars and that's all. Why is it so hard to imagine.

Comment: I got bored of arguing with you. You can't have what you want. You can have what is written in the answer above. It doesn't matter how much you shout, this is how it works.

Comment: Ok, if you're bored - that's enough. I will wait and accept your answer if someone else also say - there is no way. I hope that would be someone from Adobe. Be happy

Comment: @provance, I said it in first comments on the question.

Comment: @provance, or add filter similar to DaVinci Resolve Blanking Fill (like in vertical videos)

Comment: @RomeoNinov - Now I have another problem. See here pls - https://superuser.com/questions/1770267/