# Is there a way to get YouTube compression inside Premiere Pro?

Tags: video, compression, adobe-premiere

Trying to export small file size in Premiere Pro
Here are my params:

```
Preset - Custom
Format - H.264
Frame size - Custom - 640 x 360
Frame rate - 29.97
Field order - Progressive
Aspect - Square Pixels(1.0)
Bitrate Encoding - VBR, 1 pass
Target Bitrate - 4
Max Bitrate - 4
```

Resulting video is `120 MB`
After uploading and downloading from YouTube - the video is `34 MB` in size
And - I can't see any difference in quality

Is there a way to get this compression in Premiere ?

Comment: AFAIK Youtube use (currently) VP9 codec. Try to export with this codec

Comment: @RomeoNinov - can I get `mp4` and not `webm` file using this codec ?

Comment: AFAIK you can use WebM, Matroska containers. For MP4 I am not sure.